# How to calculate this Differential Form

Tags: differential-forms

Let $d\omega=(\frac{-3}{2}u^2D - Su + Tu - u^2 - Qu)(u^3D + Su^2 - Tu^2)^{-1}du \wedge  \omega$ 
Where $D$, $S$, $T$ and $Q$ are constants.

I don't know how to calculate $\omega$

Comment: What have you done ? First, factor the $u$ and simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to look for constants $A$ and $B$ such that
$$
\mathrm{d}\bigl(u^A(Du+S-T)^B\,\omega\bigr) = 0,
$$
then you can write $\omega = u^{-A}(Du+S-T)^{-B}\,\mathrm{d}v$ for some function $v$.

You will have to treat the special cases $S=T$ and/or $D=0$ separately, but you are still looking for an integrating factor in those cases as well.

**Added remark:**  The point is that, when $D$ and $S{-}T$ are nonzero, we obviously have a partial fractions decomposition
$$
\frac{-\tfrac32 u^2D-Su+Tu-u^2-Qu}{u^3D+Su^2-Tu^2} 
= -A\frac{1}{u} - B\frac{D}{Du+S-T}
$$
for some constants $A$ and $B$.  Calculating $A$ and $B$ is pure algebra.  This means that 
$$
\frac{-\tfrac32 u^2D-Su+Tu-u^2-Qu}{u^3D+Su^2-Tu^2}\,\mathrm{d}u 
= \mathrm{d}\left(\log\bigl({u}^{-A} (Du+S{-}T)^{-B}\bigr)\right).
$$
Now the rest should be easy.

Comment: Thank you very much professor Bryant, in my problem $S$ can not be equal to $T$ and $D$ can not be zero, then I have not treat that cases