# How to prove that the equation is not possible

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I came across another very complex equation (calculating the Gaussian curvature of a surface):

\begin{align*}\frac{-m}{2}=&(2A^2+A)(Du+k)^3u^{(3+6A+4B)}\\
&+AD(Du+k)^2u^{(6A+4B+4)}\\ &+(2ABD+4DB)u^{(6A+4B+6)}(Du+k)^{(2B+3)}\\ &+(2B^2D^2+BD^2)u^{(6A+4B+7)}(Du+k)^{(2B+2)}\end{align*}

where $A$, $B$, $D$, $k$ and $m$ are constants, the only variable is $u$.

Note that $D$ can not be zero and can not be $-1$, $A$, $B$, $m$ and $k$ can not be zero.

How can I prove that equality is not valid? i.e. that the right term cannot be a constant?

My question is related at this
[How to calculate this Differential Form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191322/how-to-calculate-this-differential-form)

Comment: Can $m$ be $0$?

Comment: If "u" is the only variable, what connection does it have to the surface?  In general the Gaussian Curvature of a surface is NOT a constant, it varies from point to point.  And, since a "surface" is two dimensional a point on the surface is identified by two parameters, not one.

Comment: @saulspatz no, sorry, now I added, Thanks

Comment: Also, this may just not be the best way to proceed with the calculation, are you sure you want to perform the calculation in this manner? Another note though, the number of unspecified constants is rather surprising. Where do they all come from?

Comment: @user247327 I have made a change of variables, $u$ is a function that here is considered a variable. I have to show that this equation is not valid to show that Gaussian curvature cannot take on certain values

Comment: Set $S-T=k, \ k\neq 0$. The two always appear together in the form $S-T$

Comment: @Rhys Hughes Thanks, now I update the question

Answer (score 2):

**Original answer:**

Note that the rhs is a polynomial, assuming $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative integers, which I suppose is unspecified. If we wanted to show that this equality cannot hold for functions of $u$, it suffices to show that the leading coefficient of $u$ on the right hand side is nonzero.

Thus let's compute the leading coefficient. The degree of the highest power of $u$ is $6A+6B+9$, so we'll consider the coefficients of these terms.

It comes out to be $(2ABD+4DB)D^{2B+3}+(2B^2D^2+BD^2)D^{2B+2}$.
Since $D$ is nonzero, we can divide this by $D^{2B+4}$ without affecting whether or not this is zero, to get the simpler expression
$$2AB+4B+2B^2+B=(2A+2B+5)B,$$
and since $B$ is nonzero, this is nonzero if and only if $2A+2B+5$ is.

Since I've assumed $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative anyway, $2A+2B+5 \ge 5 > 0$, so the leading coefficient is nonzero, so the equality fails to hold.

**Addressing the comments**

The OP has clarified that $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily either integers or positive. That said, a similar approach remains valid, but we must do casework on the signs of $A$ and $B$. Actually, note that the sign of $A$ is irrelevant, since we can factor a $u^{6A}$ out of the entire rhs and what remains doesn't have exponents that depend on $A$.

If $B\ge 0$, and $2A+2B+3\ne 0$ then since the highest exponent on $u$ is $6A+6B+9\ne 0$, we can divide both sides of the equation by $u^{6A+6B+9}$ and take the limit as $u$ goes to infinity to get that if the equality held, we must have
$$\lim_{u\to\infty} \frac{-mu^{6A+6B+9}}{2}=(2ABD+4DB)D^{2B+3}+(2B^2D^2+BD^2)D^{2B+2},$$ as before.

If $2A+2B+3 < 0$, the left hand limit is $\infty$, so the equation is never satisfied.
On the other hand, if $2A+2B+3 > 0$, the left hand limit is $0$, so we get
$2A+2B+5=0$ again, but $2A+2B+5 > 2A+2B+3 > 0$, so this is never satisfied either.

For this case it remains to address what happens when $2A+2B+3=0$, but I'll neglect this more specific case for now.

**Incomplete** I'll have to think about the other case, when $B\le 0$ later.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2AB+4B+2B^{\color{red}2}+B$ there on the LHS?

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks for catching the typo. Luckily the argument still holds.

Comment: @jgon thank you very much. If $A$ and $B$ aren't integer, what'happen?

Comment: @exxxit8 If $A$ and $B$ are positive, and don't satisfy $A+B=-5/2$, then the same argument works by simply dividing by this highest power of $u$ and taking the limit as $u$ goes to infinity. I'm not sure about how far this argument extends.

Comment: @jgon thank you, another question, you assume that the highest degree is $6A+6B+9$ but if $B$ is negative? $6A+4B+6$ maybe the highest, or not?

Comment: @exxxit8 To be more precise I was originally assuming that $A$ and $B$ were nonnegative integers, so that we had an ordinary polynomial. I edited to make this assumption clear.

Comment: @jgon ah ok thanks, If we take that $A$ and $B$ are not necessary positive and are not necessary integer we can say nothing about the question, is it correct?

Comment: @exxxit8 while I'm not sure I'd say we can say nothing, it becomes a much harder question, yes.

Comment: @jgon, my real problem is that $A$ and $B$ have no such constraints, in the sense that they could be non-integer and negative. Thank anyway for your helps

Comment: My question is related at this
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191322/how-to-calculate-this-differential-form

Comment: @jgon, but if we don't know if A and B are positive or negative, is anough consider both cases (yours) ad 6A+6+4B as highest degree, proceeding with the same analysis, in this new case, we get $2A^2=0$ since A can not be zero, the equality fails to hold. What do you think?

Comment: @jgon I think that  if we don't know if A and B are positive or negative a third case is also needed: 6A+6B+9=6A+4B+6. we need to analyze all three cases because we don't know which degree is higher.

Comment: @exxxit8 Hm, I think your comments make sense. Sorry I was offline for a while. I think I'll edit my answer to address the ideas in your comments.